# accessing Arraylist containing JPanels holding JFormattedTextFields (setText & getText)?

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel

So I have around 6 or so JFormattedTextfields inside a JPanel, and a couple dozen of these JPanels. I can put each JPanel in it's own component array using:

```
Component[] layer1 = LayerPanel1.getComponents();
etc..
```

which gives me an array of the JFormattedTextfields in that panel. I can also put the component arrays in an ArrayList using:

```
layerSet_components.add(layer1);
etc..
```

What I need to know is how to setText the text of a particular JFormattedTextfield inside the ArrayList and to also getText of a particular JFormattedTextfield.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Okay. I didn't realize.

Comment: What is the declared type of layerSet_components exactly (paste code)? And how do decide which of all those JFormattedTextfield objects you want to access?

Comment: The layerSet_components is:
    static ArrayList<Component[]> layerSet_components = new ArrayList<>();
 The JTextFields represent variables in a formula, so all of them will be accessed at some point. They are ordered in the JPanel though so they will always represent the same variable across the different layers.